# Azure Event Hubs Capture is on but no files received

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to use Azure Event Hubs to stream gaming data in and Capture them in a Storage Account. I've set the capture on but it hasn't triggered.

[image]

These are the settings
[image]
No files have been created in my blob. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't encountered this issue in a production environment. The current hypothesis is that when I created and deleted the same-named resource (Event Hubs), even though I was waiting until Azure notified me that the deletion occurred I believe some underlying parts were not being deleted accordingly. The resource was being recreated successfully but not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with default naming format? I wonder if the name format you created is causing some issues here.

Comment: Hey. I tried again and left it running for a while. The capture eventually came but quite delayed. One hour after the transmission was done.  I set the params to either 60s or 10Mb. I think it is which one comes first. I also set up 1 partition. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: There should be no delay. Did you enable idle capture as well?